# Django. How i can get list of Users with a duplicate?

Tags: mysql, django

i have array like this: [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]. How i can get users with a duplicate? For example this query return list without duplicate

```
list=     User.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 1, 1, 2, 3])
```

for example it will be users with id's:

```
1,
2,
3
```

but i need list of users like this:

```
    1,
1,
1,
    2,
    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = []
for x in [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]:
    list.append(User.objects.filter(id=x)
```

It this what you mean? I don't quite understand the spacing.

Comment: thanks, i need filter results(for example users) with a duplicates. Will be this code slow?

Comment: thanks, do you know, how i can return list of querysets? I have tried to do like this: `queryes = User.objects.none`, `for x in [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]:`, `queryes |= User.objects.filter(id=x)` but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Get your queryset sorted in the right order. `.order_by('id)` for ascending by `id` (which may be the default anyway). Then iterate over the queryset with code to make extra operations  with the same object (or a copy thereof) as dictated by the list of IDs.

```
idlist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]  
queryset = User.objects.filter(id__in = idlist ).order_by('id')      

for object in queryset:
    for _ in range( idlist.count( object.id))
        do_something_with( object)
```

Note, this is only one DB call (one queryset), unlike the accepted answer which does one DB query for each element in the id list. Not good.

Comment: thanks. But i need do another. For example my `idlist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3] ` has 5 elements, when i have writen this code `queryset = User.objects.filter(id__in = idlist ).order_by('id')` the queryset had 3 elements(user with id1, user with id2 and user with id3). I need create queryset where will be all users from the list `idlist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]  ` with a duplicates, its means i need quesryset where will be = `(user id1, user id1, user id1, user id2, user id3)`

Comment: I which case you can turn my answer into a generator function and `yield` the object instead of doing something with it. A generator can be iterated  with `for x in generator(args)` just like a queryset. Only problem is if you are going to mutate the yielded objects, in which case you need to know how to copy or deepcopy(?) a Django model instance. I know I don't know and don't have time to find out.

Comment: It really is a tricky little conundrum for such a simple sounding thing, ain't it? :)